# Wordpress Navigation Label in Browser tab

Tags: php, wordpress, navigation, page-title

I am trying to edit my header.php to call the ***navigation label*** of a page as opposed to the ***page title***. Here is the existing code...

```
<title><?php wp_title( '' ); ?></title>
```

What is the code for calling or echoing the ***navigation label*** of a menu item?

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: What is a *"navigation label"* ? Can you provide a screenshot and draw an arrow in red on top of it to point to that thing (or draw a box around)?

Comment: @hakre thanks for added the image. It is my understanding that I have to have at least 10 reputation points to add images. I also deleted my comment with a CloudApp link. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is to access the `wp_nav_menu_objects`, by first rendering the menu to extract the label in order to use it on the page `title`.

**You can see a working solution well explained on this links:**

[How to get current-menu-item title as variable?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/16337)

[first render the menu and then display it later](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/14466)