# How can I access (echo) a pages navigation label in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, navigation, label

This is a continuation in a way of this question:
[Wordpress Navigation Label in Browser tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865920/wordpress-navigation-label-in-browser-tab)
but I am afraid I need more guidance then the previous poster.

I too want to use the navigation label in the WordPress menu, to display the parent navigation label (and not the parent title!) before the page's actual title.

The code that works for the parent title is this:

```
<h1 class="page-title"><strong><?php
    // If child page , also include the parent title:
    if($post->post_parent)
    {$parent_title = get_the_title($post->post_parent);
    echo '<span>'.$parent_title.' &#8212; </span><br />';
    }
    the_title(); ?></strong></h1>
```

I would like to swap out **.$parent_title.** for the parent-navigation-label. Is there a way to echo that label?

Disclaimer: I am not a programmer by choice - only when I have to, so please be gentle...

Edit: This is the navigation label I am talking about btw:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The label is stored in the post object as `title`:

```
$parent = get_post( $post->post_parent );
echo '<span>' . $parent->title . ' &#8212; </span><br />';
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @diggy - it gives me some hope that this is possible. But when I tried replacing this code in my header file the output is nothing (except) for the - sign that shows up. So - the .$parent->title doesn't seem to work for me. (If I can just figure out how to post my code in an answer I will show you what I have done. I am not demanding or expecting you to help me out, but if you could lend some pointers to me I would be very grateful!)

Comment: '<h1 class="page-title">
    <strong><?php
    // Display the parent nav label:$parent = get_post($post->post_parent );
    echo '<span>' . $parent->title . ' &#8212; </span><br />';
    the_title(); ?>
    </strong></h1>'

Comment: you can format code in comments by putting it between backticks :)

Comment: I'm wondering, what is `$post` in the code you provided? If it's a (child) page, the parent will not have a `title` field. There is no direct correlation between your pages and any nav menu you create with these pages.

Comment: ahh - that explains it. I am trying to get display the  navigation label of a parent in a child page. So I guess that is why it doesn't work?

Comment: Yep. Nav menu items are actually posts of the `nav_menu_item` post type. I think it should be possible to get the label value by comparing the page id to the data stored the nav menu items of a specific menu, but that'll require some extra coding :)

Answer (score 0):

(Ok - If there is a way to include formatted code in the comments - please let me know!)

Building on @diggys answer I added this:

```
<h1 class="page-title"><strong><?php
// Display the parent nav label:
$parent = get_post( $post->post_parent );
echo '<span>' . $parent->title . ' &#8212; </span><br />';
the_title(); ?>
</strong></h1>
```

but the output is empty - apart from the the — character (-). I must be missing something obvious, right?